# How to get a string from a function class?

Tags: android, opencv

please help me... how to get value from fuction class and show result in primary class in android?

function class

```
 public void cekberhasil() {
    for (int i = 0; i < GRID_AREA; i++) {
        if(mIndexes[0] == 0 && mIndexes[1]==1 && mIndexes[2]==2){
            berhasil = "success";
        }else{
            berhasil = "";
        }


    }
}
```

and first class

```
//@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    Log.d(TAG, "Creating and setting view");
    mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) new JavaCameraView(this, -1);
    setContentView(mOpenCvCameraView);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(CameraBridgeViewBase.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    mPuzzle15 = new Puzzle15Processor();
    mPuzzle15.prepareNewGame();

    mPuzzle15.cekberhasil();





}
```

how to get string?? please help me

Comment: you mean like `public class X { public String method() {  return "a"; }}` ... then usage `String ret = new X().method();` Do you know java at all ?

Comment: Use a method with String as the return value as @Selvin suggested. Take it easy Selvin :P

Comment: Take some time to read the basics first. Then only get on with code. Thats what is Doing it in right way !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably get familiar with basic programing paradigms before proceeding with your app, especially method return value.

The method you're looking for should be something like this:

```
public String cekberhasil() {
for (int i = 0; i < GRID_AREA; i++) 
    if(mIndexes[0] == 0 && mIndexes[1]==1 && mIndexes[2]==2)
        return "success";
    else
        return "";       

}
```

And than compare return value

```
if( mPuzzle15.cekberhasil().equals("success")){
//do something
}
```

Comment: thanks mr/mrs. gotiasits, but error found in end of method ("missing return statement")

Comment: Check your brackets `{ }`, Or use less of them, as in updated answer...